# Why are android listeners commonly implemented within the Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, listener

I'm relatively new to Android. I'm wondering why the common pattern for implementing listeners is to implement an interface through an activity, then pass `this` to a component that needs it (i.e. fragment). Something like:

```
class MainActivity implements OnItemActionListener {
    public void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        someFragmentInitialization(this);
    }

    public void someItemAction() { //do something }
}

class MainFragment {
    private OnItemActionListener mListener;
}
```

I'm thinking it might be better to implement the interface in a separate class, not activity/fragment, just a class. Then instantiate that class inside the fragment/activity and pass the context in the instantiation (if needed). Something like:

```
class SomeImplementationClass implements OnItemActionListener {
    public void someItemAction() { //do something}
}

class MainFragment {
    private OnItemActionListener mListener;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      mListener = new SomeImplementationClass(getContext());
    }
}
```

Is this something about the Android ecosystem/lifecycle?

Comment: Better pass the predefine listeners which will be going to use in the fragment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm wondering why the common pattern for implementing listeners is to implement an interface through an activity, then pass this to a component that needs it (i.e. fragment).

It is *a* pattern, and one that you will see on occasion, particularly in educational materials. Anonymous inner classes and Java 8 lambdas/method references are the two other major candidates, besides your proposed solution. Of the four, my guess is that anonymous inner classes is the most common, and lambdas probably have the greatest current growth (since they're relatively new to Android).

> I'm thinking it might be better to implement the interface in a separate class, not activity/fragment, just a class

You are certainly welcome to do it that way. It will not always work, as there may be things that you want `private` but still have them visible to the listener, and now that is no longer possible.

Also, our listeners tend to be short, with any "heavy lifting" delegated to something else. Having dedicated top-level Java classes (and associated files) for each of those gets tedious very quickly on larger projects.

> Is this something about the android ecosystem/lifecycle?

Not really. All four approaches are roughly comparable there.

From an education standpoint, an objective is to have as little code as possible while still using widely-understood techniques. So, for example, when I started writing about Android and teaching it, I originally followed Google's example and used anonymous inner classes. I got some push-back from readers and students, as they didn't grok anonymous inner classes very well, back in 2008-2010. So, I switched to using the "implement the interface on the component" approach that you dislike, because it was the shortest solution that was fairly universally understood. Since then, I have re-introduced anonymous inner classes without issue, and I am slowly introducing lambdas/method references.

Comment: Thank you for the very concise answer. I do have a follow-up question, I am currently tinkering with an app that runs the same listener code for a Fragment and Two Activities. This lead me to the "create a separate class listener" solution that I suggested. If we use Anonymous Inner Classes here, we will still need another class/component/activity to place the shared code between the three, right? Do you think this makes sense? Thanks!

Comment: @AceDimasuhid: If there is a lot of code associated with the listener, making a common shared implementation of that code makes sense. Whether the best approach is to make the *listener* be shared, or to have that common code be in some other class that individual listeners use, would depend a bit on the situation.